# How to modify the size of Drop Shadow in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drop-shadow

I want to increase the size of the drop shadow that I am adding. In the case of Photoshop, I could change the size of the drop shadow by using the size option (and varying the spread) under Drop Shadow in Blending Options. How to do that in Illustrator.

For Example:[image: Image for Drop Shadow Question]

I want to increase the size of the drop shadow here, changing the x and the y offset has not the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change the Effect.

If it's visible in the **Appearance Panel**, click it. You can then change the settings....

[image]

Opacity, X, and Y offset should be self-explanatory. The `Blur` setting controls the overall size.

Comment: this does not change the size of the shadow. if you increase the blur, the shadow grows, yes, but it also gets weaker. there should be another setting to scale the absolute size of the drop shadow.

Comment: @w.stoettinger you are referring to the `spread` as it's used in Photoshop. Illustrator has no such option anywhere. However, there *are* much better methods to create shadows in AI other than the horribly outdated raster effects.

Comment: @Scott can you also tell how then?

Comment: @ZeynepAcarlı Gradients, meshes, or Effect > Stylize > Feather. These are *vector-based* rather than the raster-based Drop Shadow effect.